# How do I get my CPU Governor in an Android App?

Tags: java, android, performance, cpu, processor

I am making an app that behaves differently depending on what the CPU governor is set to (e.g. Performance, powersave, etc). However, I'm not sure how to get its current setting in the app itself. Does anyone know what the command would be to access it within a java class?

(To see it on your phone, go to `Settings->Performance->Profile` as well as `Settings->Performance->Processor->CPU Governor`.)

Answer (score 0):

So apparantly the information is stored in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. If you read in the file, you'll get the kind of governor it is. You can also get more cpu info by pulling the file `/proc/cpuinfo` instead, but the governor isn't included in there if you do.

```
private String getGovernor() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    //String file = "/proc/cpuinfo";  // Gets most cpu info (but not the governor)
    String file = "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor";  // Gets governor

    if (new File(file).exists()) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(aLine + "\n");

            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```